# setup:static-content:deploy needs to run very frequently

Tags: magento2, development, static-content

Why does my css keep breaking and none of the clicks works in Magento2 frequently, even without any changes done in any of xml files.

Everytime I need to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, it is very frustrating.

What can I do about it?

Comment: You might be using the incorrect Magento mode then. Can you claridy what does "even without any changes done for any of xml files." means?

Answer (score 2):

Some important things to consider:

- you should work in developer mode
- when in developer mode, do **not** run static `setup:static-content:deploy`, it will copy the files so that on the fly generation of symlinks does not work anymore.

  To make it work again, delete `pub/static/frontend` and `pub/static/adminhtml`. Do not delete the whole `pub/static` directory, because the `.htaccess` file is important for the developer mode to work.

  See also: [Which compilation commands are needed in developer mode and when?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107055/which-compilation-commands-are-needed-in-developer-mode-and-when)
- The webserver user must have permissions to create symlinks in `pub/static`. This is especially problematic if it runs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, try putting the magento into development mode.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

I also found that i needed to make sure i set the correct permissions on files to allow read write.

Also make sure you flush the cache.

```
 cache:clean                               Cleans cache type(s)
 cache:disable                             Disables cache type(s)
 cache:enable                              Enables cache type(s)
 cache:flush                               Flushes cache storage used by cache type(s)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Permissions are already set and im already in Dev mode